# can i for just one service render a .gsp and .gson view ? groovy/grails

Tags: grails, groovy, gson, gsp

For some services in my application, I need them as a web service to 
send data to another program, and i need UI also for this service.

Is that ok if i create both .gson and .gsp view for the same service?

Answer (score 0):

Grails uses [content negotiation](http://docs.grails.org/3.0.17/guide/single.html#contentNegotiation) to determine what [format](http://docs.grails.org/3.0.17/ref/Controllers/withFormat.html) to use for your response. This will allow you to render multiple formats from a single call based on the Accept header in the request. You can also set a UrlMapping of "/$controller/$action?/$id?(.$format)?" to pass a format of .xml or .json